# Função que some os digitos de um número - C++

Tags: array, c++

Boa noite pessoal, estou trabalhando num programa que gera uma matriz 10x10, com números entre 100 e 999, e por fim que realize a soma dos algarismos de cada número gerado, ex: se saiu 350, 3+5+0=8, caso saia 495, 4+5+9=18 e por aí, ou seja tenho que somar os algarismos dos 100 elementos dessa matriz individualmente, no entanto não consigo gerar a parte da soma de jeito nenhum, segue o código abaixo para ajudar.

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
void gen( int [][10] );
void prn( int [][10] );
void sel( int [][10] );
int main()
{
    int n[ 10 ][ 10 ];
    gen( n );
    prn( n );
    sel( n );
    return 0;
} 
void gen( int g[][10] )
{
    srand(time(0));
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
        for( int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++ )
            g[ i ] [ j ]= 100+ rand()%899 + 1 ;
}
void prn( int p[][10] )
{
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++ )
            cout << p[ i ][ j ] << '|';
        cout << endl;
    }
void sel( int s[][10] )
{
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        for()
}    
}
```

Comment: Sugiro diminuir o escopo da pergunta para algo como 'funcão que some os dígitos de um número'.

Comment: você escreveu um programa em C. Apenas trocou os headers. Era mesmo um programa em C?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar uma função que calcula a soma dos dígitos de um número e aplicar essa função para todos os elementos da sua matriz. Sua função seria algo do tipo:

```cpp
int raizDigital(int n) {
    int soma = 0;

    // Cria uma cópia do parâmetro `n` para manipular ao longo da função
    int x = n;

    // Repete o procedimento seguinte enquanto houverem dígitos a serem somados
    while (x > 0) {
        // Adiciona à variável `soma` o dígito atual de `x`
        // Essa operação é equivalente ao resto da divisão de `x` por 10 (32 % 10 = 2)
        soma += x % 10;

        // Avança o dígito atual de `x` em uma casa para a esquerda
        // Essa operação é equivalente à divisão de `x` por 10 (32 / 10 = 3)
        x /= 10;
    }

    return soma;
}
```